# MySQL server has gone away: Rails on Passenger (Redmine)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, passenger

I am making use of Redmine a web based software tracking tool, its perfect for my needs. However, I keep coming across this error in my production.log.

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
>   (Mysql::Error: MySQL server has gone
>   away: SELECT * FROM `issue_relations`
>   WHERE (`issue_relations`.issue_from_id
>   = 6) ):   app/models/issue.rb:234:in `after_save'
>
>   app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:196:in`
>   edit'

When I add a ticket or update a ticket I get the below error and the above is recorded in my logs. It returns this via the browser after about 15 seconds. I have tried it several times, other areas of the app work fine.

> Internal error
>
> An error occurred on the page you were
>   trying to access. If you continue to
>   experience problems please contact
>   your redMine administrator for
>   assistance.
>
> Back

I am using Ruby on Rails 2.3.8 on Phusion Passenger. Gem version 1.3.7. Active record 2.3.8. mysql (2.8.1 ruby x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32, 2.7.3 mswin32).

I am not a Ruby on Rails programmer and I am at loss on what else I can do to narrow this down. I had quick Google and found that as of rails 2.3 there is an option to reconnect so in my database.yml file I placed a reconnect true, but this didn't help!

Thanks all for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of usual suspects: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html (all checkable on the MySQL-side of things).

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the code from this Gist in a file in `{rails application}/config/initializers/active_record_connections.rb`: http://gist.github.com/238999

That said, this should probably not be happening in the first place - and if requests are taking 15 seconds to load, that also suggests that something else is going on. Can you share what appears in the logs before this error?